# Undefined name 'users' flutter dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to define variable 'users' but I get into an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfC0z.png)

I want to define [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gZ9A.png) on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e64na.png)

I was learning to make display profile on flutter like regular basic apps but it can't auto generate it

this is my full code of Profile.dart

```dart
part of 'views.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future getUser() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
      final Users users = Users (
        doc['uid'],
        doc['photo'],
        doc['name'],
        doc['phone'],
        doc['email'],
        doc['password'],
        doc['created'],
        doc['updated'],
        doc['entered'],
        doc['left']
      );
      return ProfileView(users: users);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: Text("No internet connection"));
        }
        else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Activity.loading();
        }
        return ProfileView(users: users);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[ProfileView.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSeEM.png)

I was planning to return the display to ProfileView.dart that contains a lot of widgets on there

views.dart & widgets.dart just packages only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Return `Users` in `getUser` directly (not `ProfileView`)

```
Future getUser() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot document) async {
      doc = document.data();
      final Users users = Users (
        doc['uid'],
        doc['photo'],
        doc['name'],
        doc['phone'],
        doc['email'],
        doc['password'],
        doc['created'],
        doc['updated'],
        doc['entered'],
        doc['left']
      );
      return users;
    });
  }
```

2. Use snapshot.data

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: Text("No internet connection"));
        }
        else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Activity.loading();
        }
        return ProfileView(users: snapshot.data! as Users);
      }
```

Comment: It returns "No internet connection" even tho theres some datas on my firestore
Also I tried to change "snapshot.data!" to "getUser()" but it remains same

Comment: try the edited answer, check if it shows errors

Comment: it doesnt show error, it returns to if condition whereas "if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData)". its not return to my profileview

Comment: Can you check logs to see if the data is actually being set in `final Users users` ?

Comment: Sorry, im new into this. How to know that my users is being set up on logs? i just saw blue text color on my debug console

Comment: before `final Users users` add this line: `log("Firebase data: $doc");` you should see the data next time you run.

Comment: 2 [log] Firebase data: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'

Comment: sorry, slight correction: `log("Firebase data: ${doc?.data()}");`

Comment: yes, it display the current user data

Comment: okay, I'm editing the answer again, sorry I messed up a bit